# Connected but not adjacent vertex

Tags: graphs

Are there specific terms or adjectives in graph theory to name these two situations?

- Two vertices are non-adjacent (disjoint? I have seen that the term "disjoint" is rather used for paths with non-common vertices or edges).
- Two connected non-adjacent vertices (the shortest path or paths connecting them have a lenght $> 1$).

Comment: For the first situation, I've only seen "non-adjacent", "nonadjacent", "non-neighbo[u]r[ing]".  Larger groups of vertices, no pair of which are adjacent, are an "independent set" or "stable set".  Some papers define "$u$ misses $v$" to mean $u$ is not adjacent to $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've exactly described the first situation, i.e. we indeed say that $u$ and $v$ are non-adjacent. For the second we do the same, but we want to also specify they are in the same component of $G$ which contains them if $G$ is not connected.

These are already simple and well-understood descriptions and there's nothing "more standard". However, you are also free to use your own definitions in your actual use case if it's worth it.